# switch case with display tag

Tags: jsp, displaytag

I want to display various data in Display Tag column according to what I get from Session.

***How can I integrate switch case with display tag*** `<display:column>`**?**
I want to display AAA if the unit value I get from session is 1 etc.

Here is what I want to do.

```
switch(List.unit){
                       case 1:
                            unit = "AAA";
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            unit = "BBB";
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            unit = "CCC";
                            break;
                        default:
                            unit = "undefined";
                            break;
                    }
```

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You do it with displaytag exactly as you would do it without it. Just compute the desired unit in the servlet/action dispatching to your JSP and store this unit in some bean in the request. Then access this bean in the JSP :

```
<display:column>${theBeanStoredInTheRequest.unit}</display:column>
```

Or compute it in the JSP itself, using the JSTL, but it's more verbose:

```
<display:column>
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${sessionScope.unit == 1}">AAA</c:when>
        <c:when test="${sessionScope.unit == 2}">BBB</c:when>
        <c:when test="${sessionScope.unit == 3}">CCC</c:when>
        <c:otherwise>undefined</c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</display:column>
```

Comment: hi, it is displaying all the value in the display column like this [AAA BBB CCC ]. any ideas? the value from the session scope is correctly received. Thanks.

Comment: when I try to print out unit value itself `${List.unit}`, the value is correct. 1,2,3 etc. my display table is like this `<display:table class="displayTable" id="List">`. I get the value of List from Session.Thanks.

Comment: Have you added the taglib directive for the core JSTL taglib at the beginning of your JSP? What's the generated HTML (view source)

Comment: Thanks it works. first I use `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>` and it gave me jasper exception. So when I use,`<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" prefix="c"%>`, it works well.  Thanks for both suggestion. I prefer to use your first suggestion, just pass the computed value and Dispatch to JSP. but both works well. Thanks again :)